# How do I assign the output of switch to a varaible in cshtml

Tags: razor

I want to assign the result of the switch statement to a variable so I can use it later in the page. How would I do this?

```
switch (realage)
{
    case 0: <span>Account rendered according to N.R.P.I.</span>
        <br /><span>Please submit to your m/aid.</span>
        <br /><span>Payment of this account remains your responsibility</span>
        <br />
        break;
    case 30: <span>Account rendered according to N.R.P.I.</span>
        <br /><span>Please submit to your m/aid.</span>
        <br /><span>Payment of this account remains your responsibility</span>
        <br />
        break;
    case 60: <span>Account still outstanding!  Please query immediately with you m/aid </span>
        <br />
        break;
    case 90: <span>Account still outstanding!  Please query immediately with you m/aid </span>
        <br />
        break;
    case 120: <span>Account still outstanding!  Please query immediately with you m/aid </span>
        <br />
        break;
    case 150: <span>Account still outstanding!  Please query immediately with you m/aid </span>
        <br />
        break;
    case 180: <span>Account still outstanding!  Please query immediately with you m/aid </span>
        <br />
        break;
    default: <span>Account still outstanding!  Please query immediately with you m/aid </span>
        <br />
        break;
    }
```

Thanks